# Oracle I can't alter table with a nested table

Tags: oracle

Why I get ORA-22913 when I want to alter table? ("must specify table name for nested table column or attribute")

```
DROP TYPE salaryRaise FORCE;
/
CREATE TYPE salaryRaise AS OBJECT(
   newSalary NUMBER,
   raiseDate DATE);
/
DROP TYPE salaryList FORCE;
/
CREATE TYPE salaryList IS TABLE OF salaryRaise;
/
ALTER TABLE emp ADD listOfSalaries salaryList;
NESTED TABLE listOfSalaries STORE AS salaryList_tab;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
ALTER TABLE emp ADD listOfSalaries salaryList NESTED TABLE listOfSalaries STORE AS salaryList_tab;
```